# Random ActiveRecord with where and excluding certain records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to write a class function for my model that returns one random record that meets my condition and excludes some records. The idea is that I will make a "random articles section."

I would like my function to look like this

```
Article.randomArticle([1, 5, 10]) # array of article ids to exclude
```

Some pseudo code:

```
ids_to_exclude = [1,2,3]

loop do
  returned_article = Article.where(published: true).sample
  break unless ids_to_exclude.include?(returned_article.id)
do
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at a DB specific option.

```
class Article
  # ...
  def self.random(limit: 10)
    scope = Article.where(published: true)
    # postgres, sqlite
    scope.limit(limit).order('RANDOM()')
    # mysql
    scope.limit(limit).order('RAND()')
  end
end
```

`Article.random` asks the database to get 10 random records for us.
So lets look at how we would add an option to exclude some records:

```
class Article
  # ...
  def self.random(limit: 10, except: nil)
    scope = Article.where(published: true)
    if except
      scope = scope.where.not(id: except)
    end 
    scope.limit(limit).order('RANDOM()')
  end
end
```

Now `Article.random(except: [1,2,3])` would get 10 records where the id is not `[1,2,3]`.

This is because `.where` in rails returns a scope which is chain-able. For example:

```
> User.where(email: 'test@example.com').where.not(id: 1)
User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 AND ("users"."id" != $2)  [["email", "test@example.com"], ["id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

We could even pass a scope here:

```
# cause everyone hates Bob
Article.random(except: Article.where(author: 'Bob'))
```

See [Rails Quick Tips - Random Records](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/rails-quick-tips-random-records) for why a DB specific solution is a good choice here.

Comment: The signature is different here. However using [keyword arguments](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) is far better if the order of arguments is not self evident from the name of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some like this:

```
ids_to_exclude = [1,2,3,4]
Article.where("published = ? AND id NOT IN (?)", true , ids_to_exclude ).order( "RANDOM()" ).first
```

Comment: How would I add an "AND?" I want one where published: true and is not in the range.

Comment: See @Max's suggestion about chained where calls, which tend to be cleaner: `Article.where(published: true).where.not(id: ids_to_exclude).order("RANDOM()")`